# Remove padding / spacing between label and content in a disclosure group

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, disclosuregroup

I am creating a disclosure group as follows:

```
DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $isShowingAllOpeningHours) {
    Text("Content")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .background(.red)
        .padding(.bottom, .zero)
} label: {
    Text("Title")
        .background(.green)
        .padding(.bottom, .zero)
}
.background(.yellow)
```

I've added the colors just to illustrate the point

This gives me the following the the disclosure group is collapsed

[image: Disclosure group custom SwiftUI]

And this when it is expanded

[image: custom Disclosure group expanded SwiftUI]

There seems to be some padding around the label in a disclosure group as seen by the yellow background.

Is there a way to remove this padding.

Since this disclosure group is within a scrollview, I've tried adjusting insets but this did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

The extra padding appears to be 4pt at top and bottom. This stays the same even when the text size is increased.

You can eliminate it by applying negative padding of the same amount:

```swift
Text("Title")
    .background(.green)
    // .padding(.bottom, .zero)
    .padding(.vertical, -4) //
```

[image: Screenshot]

Of course, the padding may change in a future iOS release. So you may want to restrict the workaround to versions for which you have tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own `DisclosureGroupStyle`. Make it a `VStack` with 0 spacing. You do need to reinvent the expansion logic

```
struct NoVerticalPadding: DisclosureGroupStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    configuration.isExpanded.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    configuration.label
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: configuration.isExpanded ? "chevron.up" : "chevron.forward")
                        .contentTransition(.symbolEffect)
                }
            }
            if configuration.isExpanded {
                configuration.content
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .push(from: .bottom), removal: .identity))
            }
        }
    }
}

extension DisclosureGroupStyle {
    static var noVerticalPadding: NoVerticalPadding { .init() }
}
```

At the end of the `DisclosureGroup`, add

```
.disclosureGroupStyle(.noVerticalPadding)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove the padding in `DisclosureGroups` or easily customize them with your own `DisclosureGroupStyle`. You can achieve nearly anything you desire.

For example, here I've created one that transitions and looks similar to the default disclosure group style. I hope it helps to resolve your query.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView2: View {
    
    @State var isShowingAllOpeningHours = true
    
    var body: some View {
        
        DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $isShowingAllOpeningHours) {
            
            Text("Content")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .background(Color.red)
                .padding(.bottom, 0)
        } label: {
            Text("Title")
                .background(Color.green)
        }
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .disclosureGroupStyle(ZeroPaddingDisclosureGroupStyle()) // Apply custom DisclosureGroupStyle
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView2()
}
```

**DisclosureGroupStyle Code**

```
struct ZeroPaddingDisclosureGroupStyle: DisclosureGroupStyle {
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    configuration.isExpanded.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    HStack {
                        configuration.label
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: configuration.isExpanded ? "chevron.down" : "chevron.forward")
                            .contentTransition(.symbolEffect)
                    }
                    
                    if configuration.isExpanded {
                        configuration.content
                            .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .push(from: .bottom), removal: .identity))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```